# Generate java classes for http service

Tags: java, web-services, httpwebrequest

We are trying to connect to:

```
http://resellertest.enom.com/interface.asp?command=nameofcommand&uid=yourloginid&pw=yourpassword&paramname=paramvalue&nextparamname=nextparamvalue
```

Where we need to append parameters to http url and the response from the site is xml.

Sample xml response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<interface-response>
<Contact>
<RegistrantPartyID>{FFD61956-8D43-45FB-BC38-E0EE23331503}</RegistrantPartyID>
</Contact>
<Command>ADDCONTACT</Command>
<Language>en</Language>
<IsLockable>True</IsLockable>
<IsRealTimeTLD>True</IsRealTimeTLD>
<TimeDifference>+03.00</TimeDifference>
<ExecTime>0.3164063</ExecTime>
<Done>true</Done>
<debug>
<![CDATA [ ] ]>
</debug>
</interface-response>
```

We are trying to connect to these services from java.
Is there is a way that we can auto generate java classes (corresponding to xml) as we do in traditional webservices?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to populate XML data into Java objects using an XML schema, you could try [Apache XmlBeans](http://xmlbeans.apache.org/) or JAXB. It depends whether you expect an XML Schema/DTD/RelaxNG/... structure. You could try [Relaxer](http://www.relaxer.jp/download/index.html) for RelaxNG (I think there are documents in English within the zip file, unless you can read Japanese).

(As a side note, I'm not sure if the service for the URL you've cited in your example is under your control, but putting the password in the URL with `uid=yourloginid&pw=yourpassword` doesn't seem to be a good idea.)